# Firebase authorisation error for otp auth

Tags: java, android, android-studio

getting this error message in logcat after entering the mobile number and clicking on verify.

```
2020-12-12 18:23:55.403 15226-15226/com.example.proj1 E/zzf: Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7:
2020-12-12 17:28:13.461 29510-31007/com.example.proj1 E/FirebaseAuth: [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with {
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "INVALID_CERT_HASH : Client does not match API key",
        "errors": [
          {
            "message": "INVALID_CERT_HASH : Client does not match API key",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "invalid"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
     400


2020-12-12 18:23:56.998 15226-15226/com.example.proj1 E/zzf: Failed to get reCAPTCHA token - calling backend without app verification
2020-12-12 18:23:57.660 15226-15263/com.example.proj1 E/FirebaseAuth: [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17093 null
```

help.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved the problem by redoing the whole thing.
the problem was i was also integrating gmail login in my android app. so i think the credentials for both services were clashing. i removed both things first. then created firebase project did whole thing for otp authorisation, enabled phone auth and voila the otp service was working.
then for gmail login i used the same fire base project and enabled google auth for that and this service also started working.
the problem was i think i used firebase project for otp and google cloud project for gmail. i think these clashed and i got this error.

if you need any more help let me know.

Comment: Mine worked by removing facebook login files

Comment: yes if you add multiple credentials file it causes error